# Many Tables/models belong to one main model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rubygems, belongs-to

I am building an app where there is a simple model with only title and description and and that model has different forms that a user can fill and will be displayed under that same title and description in tabular form

Example: main model being car (title: LaFerrari, Description: made by Ferrari) 
below it a table for engine specs with attributes (type: __, Description: __) 
and a few more tables.

Every table should belong to a specific car

I am not sure how to go about this problem if there is a gem or i need to create models for every table and which should belong_to main model

A little direction would be helpful

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 2):

Table for Car

```
t.string :title
t.string :description
```

Model for Car

```
has_one :engine_specs
```

Table for Engine Specs

```
t.string :type
t.string :description
```

Model for Engine Specs

```
belongs_to :car
```

This ought to help get you started. Clearly though you are going to need a lot more help than this since you do not understand simple associations. I suggest you read it up by at guides.rubyonrails.org

Comment: I concur that the original poster ought to start at the beginning. Just in case, here's the specific topic regarding this question: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html